# Algorithm for Writing a Command Interpreter

Tags: c++, c, shell

I am writing a shell that needs a command interpreter. The current pattern I am using is as follows:

```
if(strcmp(command, "my_cmd_keyword1") == 0) {
  ...
}
else if(strcmp(command, "my_cmd_keyword2") == 0) {
  ..
}
...
```

However, the number of predefined command keywords might be very huge. The if-else branching turns out to be inefficient since it has to compare with every keyword (in the worst case). Is there any more efficient way to handle this? I am using C/C++ languages for my applications.

Comment: There is no language C/C++. Pick **one**

Comment: And, yes, there is, but your question is far too broad. You might want to read about compiler constuction.

Comment: Take a look at my answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32320837/converting-input-from-stdcin-to-runnable-code-c/32320872#32320872

Comment: Use a `std::map<std::string,std::unique_ptr<MyCommandInterface>>` and do lookups.

Comment: @Olaf Well, _compiler construction_ is a bit overshoot may be.  _Interpreter building_, or something like that might fit better.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: That is mostly the same for the scanner/parser and symbol management part. Code generation is replaced by calling the execution functions instead of the code-generator functions, then executing Not sure if there is actually literature about interpreter construction.

Comment: @Olaf That many interpreted languages around I'm pretty sure there is ;-) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: No, I mean **specific** for interpreters and not for both. I never found such necessary, but YMMV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want function pointers and some kind of lookup table.  Consider

```
std::unordered_map<String, std::function<void(std::string)>>
```

or a pair of sorted

```
std::vector<>'s
```

which might be faster.

Using C++11, and ignoring the string parsing issue for now, here's how the unordered_map and std::function work together:

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void(const std::string &)>> functions;

void xyz_function(const std::string & commandLine)
{
   // this will be called
}

void register_functions()
{
    functions["xyz"] = xyz_function;
}


int main()
{
    register_functions();

    std::string completeCommandLine = "xyz parameter parameter";
    std::string exampleCommand = "xyz";

    // now look up the command, and run the function registered
    functions[exampleCommand](completeCommandLine);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

A common solution to this problem is a hash table which maps command names to function pointers. (All the functions have to have to same signature; commonly, that would consist of a pointer to the remaining command line arguments.)

C++ conveniently has `std::unordered_map` (since C++11, or check in boost), which will save you a lot of implementation effort. Posix (since 2001, at least) defines the [`<search.h>` header](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/search.h.html), which includes a simple hash map implementation. (As usual with C datastructure libraries, the associated value type is `void*`, so you need to cast to the desired datatype.) If neither of those works out for you, it's not hard to find open source hash table implementations, or even write one.